# does const create a local scope just like let?

Tags: javascript

Say I have this:

```
for(const v of [1,2,3]){
  console.log(v);
}

const v = 5;
console.log(v);
```

does that create a unique local scope for v just like `let` would? The above runs fine.

This fails, as we might expected given the above:

```
for(const v of [1,2,3]){
  console.log(v);
}

console.log(v);  // v is not defined, but if we used var instead of const, it would be defined
```

Comment: Yes, the block scoping rules are identical for `const` and `let`

Comment: You cannot declare for example, but works same way (except you cannot reassign to that variable) `for (const i = 0 ; i < ...; i++) { ... }`

Comment: Before posting a question, do a proper research (as you are supposed to), and it would have given you the answer: https://www.google.com/search?q=const+local+scope

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does - `const` is a block-scope constant declaration keyword, meaning that in your second example, `v` is only defined within the `{}` of the `for` loop. Changing it to `var` - which has function scope (it exists only within its enclosing function) - means that it's accessible outside of a `for` loop (because it's not a function).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bot let and const are block scoped. Refer to [this](https://wesbos.com/javascript-scoping/) for a clear picture on scopes of let and const.